# Plot a 2D curve having a table in Matlab

Tags: c, matlab

I am tying to plot the existing values in the following table:

[image]

and I expect to have a curve as shown in the following graph:

[image]

This is my code:

```
clc
clear all
close all
time=0:0.225;    %time interval in s
Er=0:0.69;     %energy interval in J
M=[1 5 25 51.2 52428.8 104857.6 209715.2];%[20Byte 100Byte 500Byte 1kByte 1MByte    2MByte]

En=0.00653;        %energy for 20Byte in mJ
T=[0.000002125 0.000010 0.000053 0.000108 0.115 0.222];             %Time for 20Byte s
for i=1:length(M)
  for j=1:length(T)
  z(i,j)=(M(i)*En)+T(j);   %#ok<SAGROW>
end
end
grid on
semilogx(z, 'bo-')
%legend('20 Byte','100 Byte','500 Byte','1 KByte','1 MByte','2 MByte')
title('Comparison ','FontSize',11)
ylabel('Energy Consumption','FontSize',11)
xlabel('Time in second','FontSize',11)
grid on
hold all
```

Would you tell me know how should I achieve to a logical graph with respect to table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you forget about `z` and simply

```
semilogy(T,M)
```

Or if you want:

```
semilogy(T,M*En)
```

Or maybe you want:

```
loglog(T,M*En)
```

From the table and plot you give it's not really clear whether the horizontal scale should be logarithmic or not, the first part seems to be logarithmic, but then it tapers off.

Comment: The given plot is just a guss according to the table.(T,M*En):by writing this command I receive error.

Comment: Yes, because M is of length 7 and T is of length 6, make them equal length.

Comment: Now it makes sense more.But why I can't see upward concavity? because of numerical values of table.

Comment: Yes, that is completely dependent on what is in the table, or in `T` and `M` to be precise.